# wkhtmltopdf sessions not working

Tags: php, session-cookies, wkhtmltopdf

When I make the php call: exec("./wkhtmltopdf-amd64 google.com google.pdf"), I am able to generate a pdf of google.

I need to create a pdf of my site, however, the content is dependent on sessions.  So the php command: exec("./wkhtmltopdf-amd64 myprofile.php profile.pdf") would generate a pdf file that does not have the the same content as the browser.

After some research, I found an example where someone passed session id as part of the wkhtmltopdf command.  Here is my command: exec("./wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --cookie sessionid $sessionID myprofile.php profile.pdf");

$sessionID is result of the php command: session_id();

The PDF file is never generated.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong? How do I get wkthmltopdf to use the same session data as my browser?

Comment: Your approach with the session cookie is correct. Do you pass the full URL to your `myprofile.php` script?

Comment: Yes. The url is "http://siteName.php/Test/myprofile.php?action=displayProfile".  I have tried eliminating the "http://" portion, I have added "www".  In both instances, a PDF is generated.  Unfortunately, the PDF displays without the session data I passed in.  In fact, no session is passed in.  Thoughts?

Comment: What is the full command generated by PHP that is being run? If you access that URL via browser, what happens? If you execute that command in the command line, what happens? I'd like to try it too in as original form as possible :). Also, which PHP version and which wkhtmltopdf version?

Comment: I believe one of the problems is the url itself.  The php command is: 

exec("wkhtmltopdf-amd64 www.siteName.com/profile.php?action=display&id=23" profile.pdf")

This command fails.  It also fails when I run in the command line.  When I remove the part of the url with the "&", the command works.  In other words, if the url is: www.siteName.com/profile.php?action=display, the command works.  Any ideas how I can get it to work with the "&"? I need to capture the profile id.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_COOKIE` to pass your `$_SESSION` data:
In the page where you're passing `$_SESSION` variable, convert it to a variable that selects any of the set variable [`COOKIE` or `SESSION`], since wkhtmltopdf only can access your `COOKIE`s.
Instead of

```
$sessionID = $_SESSION['sessionid'];
```

Do:

```
$sessionID = $_SESSION['sessionid'] || $_COOKIE['sessionid'];
```

OR:

```
$sessionID = !isset($_SESSION['sessionid']) ? $_COOKIE['sessionid'] : $_SESSION['sessionid'];
```

Then in the generate function, pass it like:

```
wkhtmltopdf --post BYPASS yes --cookie sessionid $sessionID ...
```

Notice that the key for *$_SESSION* is same as that of *$_COOKIE* and also the *--cookie* argument passed to **wkhtmltopdf**.